# Inserting a value every after every nth week

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sample data like this:

[image]

I want to insert number 1 in 'Identifier' column every 12 weeks BUT counting these weeks from every value equal to 1 in 'Flag' column. So if a the value is 1 in 'Flag' column on 26.1.2021 then we count 12 weeks from there and insert 1 in 'Identifier' column (week 20.4.2021), and so on.. Any formula that can do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just write `=B2` in cell C14 and drag down.

A bit more sophisticated, starting in D2:

```
=IF(ROW()>ROW(A$1)+12,INDEX(B:B,ROW()-12),0)
```

and drag down

or in Excel 365 you could use a spill formula:

```
=IF(ROW(A2:A28)>ROW(A1)+12,INDEX(B:B,ROW(A2:A28)-12),0)
```

[image]

always assuming your dates in the first column are going up in regular steps of one week.

Comment: Thanks Tom, much appreciated and great options for the solution!